PhD program but no funding?
Just started my second year in my PhD program, STEM degree. Before I entered the program the professor I had found had told me that there is some funding (albeit not a lot) he could give me on the project we had agreed I would be working on.
During registration the university said that I had to complete two courses for the ECTS and it was 1000€ with registration which I paid from my own pocket.
When I started my first year the supervisor told me that I could work on something else but similar (another candidate he had for that project never made it to register) and that he would give me a paid contract in some time. I reluctantly agreed, I had already paid 1000€.
Never heard anything about that until I asked him a few weeks ago where he said that he doesn’t have extra funds for me now. Also, he didn’t give me any goal either, ie “I’ll pay you when we publish our first paper” or something to that extent. And I had to pay another 400€ to register for this year from my pocket. Because is rent is so expensive I had to leave the city and go back to my parents for a while and continue online. To that fact, my supervisor just said that he understands and he's fine with remote.
Mostly my research depends on external institutions for data, which they either don’t have yet or are very sparse to get something substantial.
I feel kind of scammed and really losing motivation. Is this kind of normal or am I exaggerating feeling weird about my situation? This is in Spain.
EDIT: I searched and found the details of the approved funding info for the project I was assigned to work on. I started September of 2023 and the funding started June 2024 and lasts for two years. In total it's 160k (which doesn't seem a lot tbh for such as big medical project) and it's not even managed by the PI but from the institution we are working with. So from what I understand, my supervisor drew me in with funding promises when he knew very well there was no funding for months and months and in the end he doesn't even have a saying to how to allocate the funds. Does that sound correct?

I don't know the norms in Spain, but this does seem very odd. Effectively it looks as though you are self-funding a PhD, with a chance that there may be some contribution from your professor at some point down the line. It seems that you need to work out whether you can afford that / want to do that. Beware the sunk cost fallacy (and also, maybe find out whether the credit for those ETCS courses could carry over to a different project and/or a different institution)

@Flyto Thanks. You mean that I shouldn't care about what I have paid so far to make my future decisions. I'm pretty sure his other students are getting something, but I need to find more information that could be quite personal for each one.

What does your offer of admission say?  The institution is bound to give you no less than what they promised in this letter.

@ZeroTheHero I found my admission's letter. It just says that I have to complete 10 ECTS nothing about a fund..

then you are not guaranteed any funding, and should not expect to receive any.  Promises by prospective supervisors are not binding; offers of admissions are (at least in all places I know).

So I was scammed by my supervisor? By the institution?

@user159941 No, the term "scammed" isn't the right one, because the supervisor has no benefit from the current situation. Actually, communicating with you takes (working) time, too, so actually, the current benefit is negative for the supervisor as well. Note that this doesn't mean that this situation is acceptable...

@DCTLib Couldn't he be trying to get me to do work for him by not needing to deal with finance at the same time? Finance is additional extra work and expenses that he would have to deal with and allocate.

I guess I have a different opinion: scammed might be a strong word, but I don't think it's too far off. Not a scam in that the institution and degree doesn't exist, but a scam in that the funding doesn't, and OP has been drawn to working with this supervisor under promise of funding that's not coming. OP keeps being promised some future funding for doing work today; that's a scam.

I don't know about Spain but in some countries (e.g. Germany) the supervisor could be breaking the law by breaking such a promise, and they could get into a lot of trouble. I would say that at the very least it's worth seeing if your university has any kind of student advice service that you can approach, to see if they can help.

Is this allowed? I did my PhD in Spain (Barcelona) and when I started, in 2003 or so, I was told I had to have funding. I was lucky enough to have a family who could have supported me financially, but the university told me that isn't an option and in order to enroll in the PhD program, I needed some sort of funding (beca). Which, frankly, is absolutely correct!  Otherwise, only those with personal money would be able to study. I don't know if this has changes or if it was only in my university, but have you spoken to the university authorities about this?

Run, run, run.
I would consider an unfunded PhD to be equivalent to not being admitted to a PhD. This professor is willing to drag you along as you pay costs out of pocket. They know you don't know how the system is supposed to work and are abusing that lack of understanding. They will keep finding excuses why the money isn't there, because it never existed.

Thanks @Bryan Krause, that's what I needed to hear but didn't want to..

I concur. At least in the U.S., in math, an admission to a PhD with no guaranteed stipend (whether teaching assistantship or research assistanship, or some sort of fellowship), and no guaranteed tuition in addition to the stipend, is a negative indicator. True, PhD programs have limited capacity... limited finances ... but/and you don't want to find yourself outside the circle of being taken good care of by the program.

Agree with the post, but it's possible (I will not say likely) that the professor and/or institute are getting funding, but not using it for it's intended purpose.

-1: It may be the case that the supervisor is stringing the student here, but this is a US-centric answer to a question about Spain. In many places admission to a Ph.D. and funding are entirely separate things.

I know several cases where the PhD was done on the PhD money. They wanted to do it and it gave them a lot of freedom.

@MartinArgerami Even if they're separate, OP was lured to their situation with a promise of funding that didn't happen. Now they have a new promise for some future funding after they do some unpaid work in the meantime.

@WoJ I would say that whatever freedom OP had was taken from them when they were attracted to this particular program and supervisor with a promise of funding that then didn't materialize. If they knew the funding wasn't going to arrive then they indeed would have had the freedom to choose some other program.

@BryanKrause: I agree. But you wrote "I would consider an unfunded PhD to be equivalent to not being admitted to a PhD". In many places, admissions to Ph.D. programs are entirely separate from funding; not every academic system is similar to that of the US.

Just a bit more than a comment about the situation in Spain.
I'm not knowledgeable about the system because I only know some parts that affect me, but it's a bit different that the view from the USA or other countries that can be seen in other answers.
The main difference is that in the USA a PhD program is a job, and therefore a PhD with no funding is as unheard as a job without a salary.
In Spain it's a bit different. In Spain the PhD program is more similar to any other studies. In principle, you could go to a university, get accepted and pay an annual fee for tuition - not differently as if you wanted to pursue a master or any undergraduate studies.
The funding part comes quite independently from the study part. You can get a grant to finance the PhD, but that is harder than being accepted. As far as I know there are public grants - somehow similar to grants for other studies - and there are PhD offers that come with funding from some program. For the first kind you can start by googling "becas de doctorado". The second kind may be more similar to what I see in this forum about the USA - a job for the duration of the PhD program - or be something more patchy, like some jobs more or less related to your thesis topic, that may last a lot less than the program. Those jobs can come nicely one after another without gaps, or can just disappear for years.
I wouldn't say your situation is a scam. Maybe your advisor expected to be able to offer you a job at some point, or maybe he didn't but if he didn't promise it, it isn't a scam.
In summary, I think you need to learn how the system works in Spain and in the particular context of your field and your university. I would suggest to start by googling about predoctoral grants in Spain but also meeting and asking other grad students in your university. Starting to search for a funded PhD program may also be a good idea, but don't expect to easily find what the American participants in this forum would see as normal.
Additionally, you may search for teaching opportunities, although the part time lecturers positions that you can get without a PhD in Spain (or even with a PhD) are temporary and very low paying - and recent legislative changes have made them even worse.
And an end advice: You didn't say which is your field, but please beware that getting a PhD may not be a wise financial decision in Spain, even if it's a funded PhD. There are a lot of good reasons to pursue a PhD, but when deciding whether to continue, please don't factor in the expectation of recovering your investment with a good PhD job unless you know very well the job situation for PhD holders in your field.

Thanks for your input @Pere. The reason I went with this program was exactly because the supervisor said that there would be funding. I turned down others in similar programs that explicitly told me that there weren't able to fund me but I could look into grants by myself. I want to be open minded and consider that the professor actually thought there would be funds, but at some point months ago he said that he had to pay his freshly graduated doctorate student and give them a post-doc position, and there was no more money after that. My field is AI focusing in medicine.

About the situation in the U.S.A., it is generally not true that Ph.D. students automatically have a job and must be funded. In my department (mathematics), most of our Ph.D. students also have jobs (and are paid) as teaching assistants or research assistants, and they are usually offered these jobs at the same time that they are offered admission to the Ph.D. program. But it is entirely possible to offer admission without offering a job (and so without funding). This has been done when the student already has other funding (e..g., from a scholarship or an oil-rich home country).

"In Spain the PhD program is more similar to any other studies.": Are you sure about that? When I did my PhD in Spain, my university (Pompeu Fabra) wouldn't allow me to enroll in the PhD program unless I obtained some sort of funding. I specifically asked if I could support myself and was told that no, I needed external funding. This was 20 years ago now, and things may very well be different, or it might have been specific to my university (but all of my friends were in the same situation, even those from other institutes).

@terdon - Yes, I'm sure about that. In Universitat de Barcelona funding is not a condition for enrolling in a PhD. In Universitat Ramon Llull (which is a private university) it's even more extreme and they explicitly state that PhD aren't jobs but studies and students are required to pay a non-negligible amount for tuition.

You have to pay tuition at a regular university in Spain? (asking because we don't in France and I thought it was a rule (my experience is limited to France, Germany and Poland))

@WoJ - Yes, although the tuition for undergrads course in a public university can be about 10% or 20% of what it would be at a private one, and a lot of people can get some grants from the State to cover tuition fees.

@terdon Maybe it depends from institution to institution, nobody had ever mentioned funding or grants through my enrollment. Besides my supervisor when I was looking for PhD programs and he told me that he could give me a contract, again he didn't mention anything about grants. This is in Madrid.

I asked around to see how his other students are funded. One has a contract that the supervisor gave him after a few months of starting, and the other two have becas (grants).

I found the bigger project in an EU website about public funding. It's around 160k EUR, status of "Forthcoming" and says it starts the 01 June 2024, 9 months after I joined...

We don’t have the entire story but from your account, I would avoid the word “scam”: you were in fact not promised anything, so suggesting intent to scam you is a bit of a stretch. We can’t say if supervisor was or was not aware of the realistic probabilities of funding, but what you can say is that neither the institution nor the supervisor were very transparent as to the likely costs to you.
In addition, it’s difficult to believe your supervisor and their institution  have placed your academic interest at the forefront.  There may have been pressure on your supervisor from the institution to accept unfunded students, but I would argue a good supervisor would clearly communicate to a prospective student, especially an unfunded student, what the expectations are in terms of funding either already in place or forthcoming.
This is why you need to check official documents carefully.  Regrettably, some students will get starry-eyed by an offer of admission, make all kinds of assumptions, and sign an offer without understanding the contents or the consequences (especially financial).
However you look at this, there seems to be limited reasons for you to stay in this program.  Physical onsite presence is a major benefit to students because they can interact with others and faculty, attend seminars and participate in the ensuing discussions, use more easily the available resources and generally be immersed in the research environment.  I fail to see how the current set up realizes any of this for you.

I understand that scam is quite heavy and hyperbolic, it just matches the feeling I get when thinking about it all. As I said above, in my admission's letter it just states that I have to complete 10 ECTS, nothing about a fund. I didn't have to sign anything, just when I registered I had to pay for the courses and I was automatically enrolled. But true I didn't know anything about how financing works, I just believed my supervisor. @ZeroTheHero thanks for your answer

based on what I know, I wouldn't use the word "scam".  It may indeed be a scam, but it's not clear there was an intent to mislead you.  I think you fell into a common trap of assuming a lot of stuff.  I'm sorry to say you're not the first to fall into this trap, and you won't be the last. I do not like it when faculty or universities are not transparent about funding, and I think not proactively disclosing this information is not right, but I work at a place where the information is provided to the students yet they don't read it and feel "scammed".

... not saying it's your case... but the difference in expectations and information between the student (particularly international students) and the institution is such that clarity and transparence are especially important to avoid bad experiences.  Of course some people just don't care but long term this cannot be good for the supervisor or the institution.

don't get me wrong: the institution and/or the supervisor are at fault for placing you in this situation without being clear ahead of time of this possible outcome.

I would expect that the rules within different EU countries are similar. You should receive a draft of your work contract or some other formal confirmation of the institution's commitment to pay you the salary or scolarship before you actully come there. What you described totally looks like scam, and I would also recommend to run away from there and find a reasonable PhD position in another institution.

Thanks @Vosoni. So you are saying that I should have received a contract of funding or stipend with my admission? And that is the norm in the EU.

@user159941 Yes, there should be some contract agreement in writing that specifies you are a PhD student. Even if you are an unpaid PhD student, there would still be a contract that explicitely says so.

The UK has the concept of unfunded PhDs. They aren't common (at least not in STEM), but perfect legal and valid. These students are formally enrolled as PhD students with the university and will have to pay the student fees. Beyond that there's no contract.

@Marianne013 - So you are basically saying that this scam is spread UK-wide. I still think it is not OK not to inform the student about this trap right after he or she applies to this program.

@Vosoni it's not a scam.  A significant proportion of PhDs in the humanities aren't funded because there aren't any grants to support students, so there's nothing illegal or scammy about this.  What we don't know if how "unique" is the situation of the OP, and how much did the institution and/or supervisor not proactively disclose. It may be that international students will not understand the funding rules whereas UK students more likely than not will, so one would think those in charge should have a fiducial obligation to be clear with non-UK applicants.  This is different from a scam.

Part of the issue is international students initially view education abroad through the lens of their own education experience.  Students habitually underestimate  the cost of rent, books, food etc because books are cheap where they live, or they think cheap food is easy to find etc.   The ethically grey area of how much information does the institution provide to make a realistic decision, especially as the Uni functions on the false premise that students will understand that no promises mean exactly that, knowing that students often assume they will be funded once accepted.

What we have with the OP is the oft-repeated situation where one party (the university) holds all the correct information whereas the other party (the student) does not, and in fact often has illusions about the information.

The scam part would be the promise of funds and then not intending to actually deliver them. An unfunded PhD may be a questionable financial move but if everyone is clear and understanding that the student is funding their own way, I would not call it a scam. Once it comes with a promise, whether it's funding in the short term or an empty promise of a guaranteed job at graduation, scam comes back into play.

@BryanKrause absolutely.   (some) universities are desperate for funding and will be economical with the consequences to a student of accepting an offer.

The expectation in the first sentence is misguided. Education is a national competence, not a European one. (Sometimes it's not even national, e.g. in Germany it's not a federal matter). Therefore there's no reason to assume equal rules across the EU. There are common concepts, e.g. the entire notion of universities, professors and PhD, but even those are not specific to the EU.

You are certainly right about the education, but we are talking here about the employment and salary. Whether or not you are employed and are getting a salary (which is typical for PhD students in Germany) or some sort of stipend should be based on written contracts. The situation when someone moves to another country or city to do a PhD but not knowing if they are paid or not, under what conditions, and from what date sounds to me like a violation of the employment regulations. For foreigners, they have consequences, in particular, for getting a Schengen visa, so should be common in Europe.

@MSalters - I am by no means a lawyer, and I have little to no experience with PhD programmes outside Germany. Nevertheless, working on a project without any official status or contract (even if it means no payment) would be considered illegal in most European countries. Doing PhD research without any kind of agreement with the lab (which is not the same as enrolling as a PhD student at the university) risks not having insurance in case of lab accidents, and whenever a scientific result is published, it is not clear why the PhD student should list that lab as his/her affiliation.

@BryanKrause - Not being clear about whether a PhD program is paid or not is already a scam, in my opinion. If it is not paid, there should be a corresponding contract that states (ideally with big red letters on the first page) that the student is expected to do research work for the faculty and publish papers for them without getting paid.

@Vosoni: That first statement is pretty much untrue in the entire EU. Working on a volunteer project is universally allowed. You might be thinking about employment, but in the EU PhD positions are considered to be a part of education (national competence) instead of the internal labor market (EU competence). Reading papers in perparation for a pHD would be entirely legal without a contract; lab access is a specific other matter. Affiliation is an academic convenience, not a legal matter.

@MSalters - In Germany, the doctorate and employment are essentially separate. Of course, you can write a thesis and submit it to the university without ever visiting the institution. However, in order to obtain results for your thesis, you would normally need to do research (at least in physics), which has to be done in a laboratory. It is common practice for this work to be done for the university and paid for, but you are then allowed to use the results in your thesis.

I know that the situation in the humanities is very different, but a short Google search is enough to see that in physics the situation in Spain is very similar. For example, here is an ad for an open PhD position in Barcelona that has very similar conditions to what I am used to: https://scholarshipdb.net/scholarships-in-Spain/Ph-D-In-Soft-Condensed-Matter-Systems-Fundaci-Bosch-I-Gimpera=rqJpP6Lh7hGUYwAlkGUTnw.html

This answer would benefit from restricting the message to specific fields. Yes, STEM positions usually involve some payment because we compete with industry.  No, this is not universally true and in many domains it is normal to have little to no funding.

I obtained my PhD in STEM (Biology) in 2006 in Spain. Many of us went for several periods without funding while on it. My account is about 1.5 years with no funding out of 6 years. At the time, PhD fellowships did not contribute to pension. It is then possible that your supervisor and many others that lived that system are just perpetuating the problem.
The feeling was that you were lucky you can do a PhD (even paid from your own pocket), and lucky that you are given the chance to help in the practical demonstrations, and lucky to help training more junior students. You were considered a student, not a worker.
I agree with previous advice: look for predoctoral fellowships and explore your local council and country fellowships. Ask in forums of pre- and postdoctoral students. Consider moving country (Marie Curie fellowships, etc.). Most of all, consider what's your goal after the PhD, and what options a PhD opens that you would really be interested in. In Spain, generally, a PhD opens the academic route, as your need one to become a lecturer at university. For industry jobs a PhD can open some positions, but starting with a degree you can still get to those roles. Also, as a PhD you would expect a higher salary, so in some cases it could be even harder for you to get a job because some companies rather have cheaper workers.
So, I'd say dig in and investigate, weigh pros and cons. There is no really bad decision or regret as long as you are convinced to go ahead with it, and the fact you are asking shows you are already thinking on it. The fact you are in an English-speaking forum shows you are looking beyond.

Hi @Rubbaa thanks for the input. What do you mean "convinced to go ahead with it"? What are you referring to? Thanks
